# .com/feed .com/en/feed/ blocked by .htaccess and can't locate the corrupted line

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, rss

Recently, we are having resource issues in the hosting environment and realized that our RSS url is having issues. I believe it is the culprit. Since we are a publishing agency we need to use RSS.

[image]

[image]

What kind of line I should look for in .htaccess to get it fixed?

Thanks.

Comment: What issues are you having with your RSS feed? Also, why do you think your .htaccess file is what's causing the problem(s)?

Comment: Feeds do not load as usual. When we enter the url and hit enter it tries to download application/rss+xml. And when we check with validator, it gives Sorry

This feed does not validate.

    Server returned HTTP Error 403: Forbidden.

Hosting company says it validetes and loads normal with standart .htaccess.

It is causing cpu peak continously

Comment: If so, then please edit your question and include the contents of your .htaccess file so we can check it out.